# How to send Post Request from axios, can I right

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

```
axios.post(url, { data : obj})
```

I attend a interview and interviewer  say question post from axios

Answer (score 0):

```
const URL = "http://localhost:5500/register";

let data = {
 name: 'dalpat',
 email: 'test@gmail.com'
};

axios.post(URL, {
data: data;
})

// Routes
app.post("/register", (req, res){
  const {name, email} = req.body.data;
  res.send({name: name})
})
```